# Angular 5 Databinding Not working when using router.navigate

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, data-binding, routes

I am trying to navigate to another route using router.navigate. The route loads fine and I get the data from my api but I cannot get the data to print on the template file. It works fine when the page reloads but not on the custom code for navigation.

```js
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-notice-edit',
  templateUrl: './notice-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notice-edit.component.css']
})
export class NoticeEditComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {

  notice_id: string;
  notice_title: string;
  notice_description: string;
  notice_expiry_date: string;
  notice_type:string;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient, private router: Router, private route:ActivatedRoute) {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function() {
      return false;
    };
    route.params.subscribe(params=>{
      this.notice_id = params['id'];
      this.ngOnInit();
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/notices/'+this.notice_id).subscribe(data=>{
      this.notice_title = data.notice_title;
      this.notice_expiry_date = data.expiry_date;
      this.notice_type= data.notice_type;
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    alert(1);
  }

}
```

```js
<p>{{notice_type}}</p>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="notice_title" [(ngModel)]="notice_title" #ctrl="ngModel"/>
  <input type="text" name="notice_expiry_date" [(ngModel)]="notice_expiry_date"/>
  <select name="notice_type" [(ngModel)]="notice_type">
    <option value="Managerial Notice" >Managerial Notice</option>
    <option value="Common Notice" >Common Notice</option>
    <option value="General Meeting Minutes">General Meeting Minutes</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

This component is then called using jQuery Click event binding like this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.edit_click',function(){
    object.router.navigate(['/notices','edit',$(this).attr('id')]);
});
```

Comment: Why are you using jQuery in your Angular app?